# How do I nest image filters in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am adjusting the filter with checkboxes.

However, contrary to the intention, the filters were not nested.

Also, if one checkbox is cleared, the image is restored even if other checkboxes are checked.

How can I nest filters and make only that filter disappear when I uncheck the checkbox?

```
def image_show(image):
    canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=canvas.image, anchor="nw")

def press1():
    if(var1.get()==1):
        img_BLUR = image_call.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
        image_show(img_BLUR)
    elif(var1.get()==0):
        image_show(image_call)

def press2():
    if (var2.get() == 1):
        img_EMBOSS = image_call.filter(ImageFilter.EMBOSS)
        image_show(img_EMBOSS)
    elif (var2.get() == 0):
        image_show(image_call)

def press3():
    if (var3.get() == 1):
        img_CONTOUR = image_call.filter(ImageFilter.CONTOUR)
        image_show(img_CONTOUR)
    elif (var3.get() == 0):
        image_show(image_call)

check_btn1 = Checkbutton(new, variable=var1, text="BLUR", command=press1)
check_btn2 = Checkbutton(new, variable=var2, text="EMBOSS", command=press2)
check_btn3 = Checkbutton(new, variable=var3, text="CONTOUR", command=press3)
```

I know roughly what the problem is.

It's probably because image_show is called with a new value every time the filter is processed.

So, filters cannot overlap, and if any checkbox is cleared, the image will be restored to its original state.

Comment: Please don't tag your IDE unless the problem *directly has to do with using your IDE*. Please *do* tag libraries that are *directly relevant to the problem*, such as tkinter in this case.

Comment: Then use `itemconfig()` method of canvas

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the three `pressN` functions into a single function, within it sequentially modify the image with each filter one after another (conditional on the state of `varN`), then display the image once it's ready with all the selected filters applied.